# Does the Java/Hibernate Criteria Query API Protect Against Injection?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, criteria, hibernate-criteria

This might be a dumb question, but I have not seen anything in the docs explicitly stating that criteria queries are parameterized or otherwise injection-protected under the hood.

In other words, is a predicate like the following directly vulnerable to injection attacks? If so, how do I fix it? Looking around the docs I don't see any options for parameterization or anything similar.

```
criteriaBuilder.like(
    root.get("prop"),
    "%"+userInput+"%"
)
```

Comment: Why do you care whether it is parameterized? What you do care about is whether there's an injection vulnerability.

Comment: Sure, fair enough. I just worded it that way because parameterization is the first thing that comes to mind in terms of a consistent way to provide decent defense against injection, and it would line up with the structure of the API. But you're right, their implementation details aren't directly relevant to the outcome, nor do they make sense to ask about directly. I'll reword my question.

Comment: I would assume that any *good-quality* library doesn't allow SQL injection attacks, unless otherwise specified. However, note this only applies to *good-quality* libraries. Hibernate seems like one to me, but I've never used it.

Comment: Roger that - that's also my assumption, though it'd be nice to just find the line in the docs where they check the box off explicitly for me. :)

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily be documented - just like they probably wouldn't document that it's free from shell injection attacks, or Lua code injection attacks, or XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, hibernate is using parameterized queries for criteria*

The easiest way to confirm this, is to activate the sql logging (set org.hibernate.SQL category to DEBUG) and you'll see the queries produced by hibernate (and to get parameter values, activate the log category : org.hibernate.type to TRACE level).

*in criteria you can write sql section by hand (using `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("...")`). If you are writing sql that is prone to sql injection there, your criteria query will be subject to it too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

Using Criteria API is the same as using parametrized PreparedStatements. The only thing you need to be cautious about is not to concatenate the query string or if it's really needed be very very careful.